# Hover при наведении на изображение

Tags: css3, hover, img

Как сделать такой hover эффект при наведении на изображение?

[image: Hover]

Comment: Эффект, типо размывается фон картинки, а остается лишь "View More"? Или я как-то не понимаю, ибо картинка не в GIF-формате.

Comment: Добавил другую картинку

Comment: Картинка слева совершенно может быть другой. Эффект на ней называется - "Боке". Плюс размытый слой сверху. Это лучше делать в фотошопе. И потом по наведению менять  бекграунд у элемента и показывать content у псевдоэлемента.

Comment: Уже было тут где-то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно поняла ваш вопрос, внизу сообщения код, который позволяет менять отображение блока при наведении.
Внутренний элемент спозиционирован абсолютно и скрыт в изначальном состоянии с помощью:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 100%;
```

Потом, при наведении на блок-родитель позиция элемента меняется на:

```
top: 0;
```

---

Контент в скрытом блоке отцентрован по вертикали и горизонтали с помощью [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

---

```css
.item {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.item_child {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item_child-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transition:top .3s linear;
  background-image: url(https://loremflickr.com/320/240);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item_child:hover .item_child-inner {
  top: 0;
}

.item_child-inner a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item_child">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <div class="item_child-inner">
      <a href="#">view more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Я просто заменил background-image: url(https://loremflickr.com/320/240); на background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 0.7); и получилось то что надо.